# Is using <name> attributes inside <span>s considered bad practice, and why?

Tags: html

I have a `<div>` displaying the result fetched from backend. This `<div>` contains a bunch of children `<span>`s, with each corresponding to a named value from the backend returned result. Like this:

```
<div id="result-display">
  <span name="name-one"></span>
  <span name="name-two"></span>
</div>
```

For each updating cycle, the script just looping through all the `<span>`s with an attribute of `name`, and fill the value into it.

In testing, it works. But I've found out that using `name` attribute for elements other than `input` is considered bad practice. Why?

Comment: `<button>, <form>, <fieldset>, <iframe>, <input>, <keygen>, <object>, <output>, <select>, <textarea>, <map>, <meta>, <param>`. Other elements don't have a `name` attribute. If you use it on elements it's not specified for you're invalidating your HTML because you're then applying a custom attribute, and custom attributes on standard HTML elements must be prefixed `data-`. Compare https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes

Comment: If I never try to please the validator, does it matter? It works perfectly though.

Comment: It may work today in browsers x, y and z. It can stop working tomorrow, or in 2 years, at basically at any point in time. It is always a bad idea to write code based on the error tolerance of systems, to rely on *unspecified* behaviour. There is wide-spread agreement on invalid HTML not being an option, *ever*. Also, why would you insist on invalid HTML when there are valid, cheap alternatives?

Comment: @connexo I found your advice very enlightening. I've never thought of this point. Why don't you make it a formal answer? I'll adopt that.

Comment: Your question already has an answer in the duplicate.

Comment: @connexo Yeah, never thought that a `name` without the prefex `data-` would be automatically considered a `customer`. Very enlightening!

Comment: custom !== customer

Comment: @connexo That was a typo. Yes, no kidding, this one is a very useful tip for me!